# Getting '08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (0) (SQLExecDirectW)'

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I'm using pyodbc with Microsoft SQL Server database on CentOS. Things working fine but after some time suddenly I start getting `'08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (0) (SQLExecDirectW)'`. I looked for solution and got suggestions like database performance issue, network connectivity issue which I checked and working fine. It is even not generating trace file.

**My configs**

```
/etc/odbc.ini

[sqlserver]
TraceFile  =  /tmp/odbc.trace
Trace      =  1
Driver=FreeTDS
Description=ODBC connection via FreeTDS
Server=***
Port=1433
ServerName=sqlserver
Database=***

odbci.ini
[sqlserver]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = ODBC connection via FreeTDS
Host = ***
Port = 1433
ServerName = sqlserver
Database = ***
TraceFile  =  /tmp/odbc.log
Trace      =  Yes
```

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like your DSN is set up to use `FreeTDS`, but your actual connection is using the `ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server` as a driver. Which driver are you trying to use? Can you please include your Python connect string (`pyodbc.connect()`)?